# Compile asio with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, boost-asio

I tried to compile HTTP Server from here http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.11.0/doc/asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#asio.examples.cpp11_examples.http_server with gcc.
I used

```
 g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -I/home/gabi/Downloads/asio-1.11.0/include -pthread
```

I get this

```
/tmp/ccE1vIzF.o: In function `http::server::server::server(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)':
server.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `http::server::connection_manager::connection_manager()'
server.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `http::server::request_handler::request_handler(std::string const&)'
/tmp/ccE1vIzF.o: In function `http::server::server::do_accept()::{lambda(std::error_code)#1}::operator()(std::error_code) const':
server.cpp:(.text+0x52a): undefined reference to `http::server::connection_manager::start(std::shared_ptr<http::server::connection>)'
/tmp/ccE1vIzF.o: In function `http::server::server::do_await_stop()::{lambda(std::error_code, int)#1}::operator()(std::error_code, int) const':
server.cpp:(.text+0x5e9): undefined reference to `http::server::connection_manager::stop_all()'
/tmp/ccE1vIzF.o: In function `_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4http6server10connectionEE9constructIS3_IN4asio19basic_stream_socketINS6_2ip3tcpENS6_21stream_socket_serviceIS9_EEEERNS2_18connection_managerERNS2_15request_handlerEEEEvPT_DpOT0_':
server.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4http6server10connectionEE9constructIS3_IN4asio19basic_stream_socketINS6_2ip3tcpENS6_21stream_socket_serviceIS9_EEEERNS2_18connection_managerERNS2_15request_handlerEEEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4http6server10connectionEE9constructIS3_IN4asio19basic_stream_socketINS6_2ip3tcpENS6_21stream_socket_serviceIS9_EEEERNS2_18connection_managerERNS2_15request_handlerEEEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x8b): undefined reference to `http::server::connection::connection(asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp, asio::stream_socket_service<asio::ip::tcp> >, http::server::connection_manager&, http::server::request_handler&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know why?
if I try to compile http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.11.0/doc/asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html#asio.examples.cpp11_examples.allocation works.

Comment: Get some IDE to help you with this task. Or learn how to use makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let me say that it seems you have provided the wrong compilation command to produce that error message, since the error message indicates that you're compiling `server.cpp`, e.g.:

```
server.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to 'http::server::connection_manager::connection_manager()'
```

when you're actually not. In fact, you're only compiling `main.cpp`, since that's the only cpp file that's in the compilation command you gave.

As another answer states, you need to compile *all* of the .cpp files for the HTTP server, not just `main.cpp`. To do that, you simply pass all of the .cpp files to your `g++` command:

```
g++ main.cpp connection.cpp connection_manager.cpp mime_types.cpp reply.cpp request_handler.cpp request_parser.cpp server.cpp -std=c++11 -I/home/gabi/Downloads/asio-1.11.0/include -pthread
```

---

And finally, contrary to what another answer says, you do **not** need to link against any libraries, because Asio is a header-only library. Boost.Asio, however, is not header-only, and so *if* you were using Boost.Asio, you'd need to link to the Boost 'System' library with the following linker flags:

`-L/path/to/folder/containing/Boost/libs/ -lboost_system`

(This is assuming that the Boost libraries are not installed in a standard system location, such as `/lib`; if they were, you could omit the `-L` flag. As was stated in a comment, `-lboost_system` tells the linker (`ld`) to look for a library called `libboost_system.so`. See the `ld` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) for more information on how `ld` finds libraries.)

However, since, as you said, you are only using Asio and not Boost.Asio, you are fine with just including the appropriate .hpp header files and using the `-I` compiler flag to point to the header file locations.

Comment: Why would server.cpp need to be added to the compilation line? The linker is reporting errors in server.cpp, so it looks like it is already being pulled in.

Comment: @DmitryRubanovich You're right. But based off of the OP's compilation command, they _didn't_ pull in server.cpp, so they must have pasted a different compilation command from the one that was actually used to produce this error. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You should compile all cpp files - not only main.cpp.

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/asio/tree/master/example/cpp11/http/server - there is makefile for boost build system.

Comment: But I use version non-boost